# Using awk and looping through files in a directory

Tags: bash, awk

I have a reviews_folder which contains different files like hotel_72572.dat

Each file contains a number of reviews structured like this:

```
...
<Overall>4
...
```

My aim is to calculate the average overall of all reviews for each file(hotel) using a averagereviews.sh script.
By executing: `./averagereviews.sh path_to_reviews_folder`
I should obtain this output:

```
hotel_11212.dat 3.51
hotel_2121.dat 2.62
hotel_31212.dat 2.43
...
```

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$1" || exit 1
for file in "$1"; do
awk 'count+=sub(/<Overall>/, ""){sum+=$0}END{print sum/count}' file;
done
```

The problem is that it doesn't recognize file as a directory and if I put hotel_*.dat it would do the average of all existing files in reviews_folder and not for each of them.

Comment: Edit reverted as the question made absolutely no sense with 70% of it deleted.

Answer (score 5):

With a single **`awk`** script (without `for` loop and multiple `awk` invocations):

Sample input files:

```
$ head reviews_folder/hotel_*.dat
==> reviews_folder/hotel_111.dat <==
<Overall>1
<Overall>4
<Overall>3

==> reviews_folder/hotel_222.dat <==
<Overall>11
<Overall>5
<Overall>7

==> reviews_folder/hotel_333.dat <==
<Overall>7
<Overall>4
<Overall>10
```

---

```
awk -F'>' 'fn && FILENAME != fn{ 
              sub(".*/", "", fn);
              print fn, sprintf("%.2f", sum/n); sum = 0
          }
          { sum += $2; n = FNR; fn = FILENAME }
          END{ 
              sub(".*/", "", fn);
              print fn, sprintf("%.2f", sum/n)
          }' reviews_folder/hotel_*.dat
```

The output:

```
hotel_111.dat 2.67
hotel_222.dat 7.67
hotel_333.dat 7.00
```

Answer (score 3):

With a few enhancements to your script,

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$1" || { printf 'unable to navigate to target\n' >&2; exit 1 ; }
for file in *.dat; do
    test -f "$file" || continue
    awk 'count+=sub(/<Overall>/, ""){sum+=$0}END{print (count)?(sum/count):0}}' "$file"
done
```

1. Since you are already `cd`-ing to `"$1"` you don't need `for file in "$1"`, but just loop over the file extensions needed `for file in *.dat`
2. The condition `test -f "$file" || continue` will make sure if there are no files in the path being looked at, a graceful exit from the for-loop happens instead of passing an unexpanded glob to `awk` to process
3. Pass the file name as `$file` instead of a literal string `file`. The shell variables need to prefixed with a `$` sign before the name and usually needs to be double-quoted.
4. A minor enhancement in the `END` clause of `awk` to check if the count is non-zero before dividing with it.

Answer (score 1):

`for file in "$1"` will run the loop exactly once, with `file` set to the literal value of the first argument to the script. Since `"$1"` is quoted, any wildcards within are not expanded. If you pass a directory to the script, you'll also pass the directory name to `awk`, and it's likely to not like that much, my `gawk` says:

```
gawk: warning: command line argument `/tmp/test/' is a directory: skipped
```

If you want to run the loop over each file individually, use a wildcard in the proper place. The `*` here will expand to the filenames in the current directory, the one given as argument since we just did a `cd` there:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$1" || exit 1 
for file in * ; do
    awk '...' "$file"
done
```

---

Alternatively, you could pass a list of file names as argument to the script, and then loop over those:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@" ; do
    awk '...' "$file"
done
```

In practice, you'd do `myscript /some/path/hotel*.dat` and let the shell expand the file names to the scripts command line. `"$@"` expands to the list of command line arguments.

---

That said, the `awk` script is a bit off, too. As you wrote it, the condition to the first rule is `count+=sub(/<Overall>/, "")`. That's true whenever `count` is nonzero after the addition, regardless of what `sub()` returned this time around. This means the rule `{sum+=$0}` runs every time after `<Overall>` is seen at least once. It will sum without increasing `count`.

You'll probably want something like this:

```
awk '/^<Overall>/ {sub(/<Overall>/, ""); count += 1; sum += $0} END {print sum/count}' "$file"
```

To display the file name, you could `echo` it:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$1" || exit 1 
for file in * ; do
    printf "%s " "$file"
    awk '/^<Overall>/ {sub(/<Overall>/, ""); count += 1; sum += $0} END {print sum/count}' "$file"
done
```

Comment: passing a directory to POSIX Awk is a fatal error

Answer (score 0):

Use below command against each file You will get the average . Tested and worked fine

Input

```
<Overall>1
<Overall>4
<Overall>3

i=`awk '{print NR}' hotel_111.dat| tail -1 `

awk -F ">" -v i="$i" 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum=sum+$2} END{print FILENAME;print  sum/i}' hotel_111.dat  | sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
hotel_111.dat 2.66667
```